# What is this thing in browsers called in English?

Tags: word-request

Normally when surfing on sites we have on the site **a thing in which we can move the site up or down** (see image bellow with a red arrow). I would like to know what this thing is called, and what's the accurate verb for this action?

(does move up or move down work here? In my native language we use a word that's translated into "roll up /down" but Oxford dictionary doesn't know such meaning to my context.)

I really don't know what it is called in my native language (normally people say "roll up the page or the site"), so I don't have a lead where to start from.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a vertical **[scroll bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrollbar)** (a horizontal scroll bar would be exactly the same thing, only in the horizontal direction).

The related verbs would be **to scroll up** and **to scroll down**:

> A touch-sensitive slider allows people to scroll up and down or zoom in and out of a document, Web page, or photo. ([source](https://www.thefreelibrary.com/Five+Logitech+Products+Win+Japan%27s+Good+Design+Award+2006-a0154170292))
>
> Can you just scroll all the way down to the bottom of the page? That's where they have their contact information.

[image]

Comment: Should I say "please, **scroll** the **scroll bar** down to the bottom of the page" or should I say "Scroll the bar down to the bottom"?

Comment: I think you can ether just scroll up or down or you can scroll up or down the page or the screen. But you don't scroll up or down the scroll bar itself. What you can do with the scroll bar, however, is that you can move it up and down. *Please, scroll the scroll bar down to the bottom of the page* -- I don't think this sentence makes sense. This is how it works: **Moving the scroll bar up and down allows you to scroll up and down the page**.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that element of a scroll bar is technically called the 'thumb', but only by deep computery types (programmers, maybe UI designers).